# How to run iphone application in background for long time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to run my iphone app in background and it is working fine but after 15  mins system terminates it.I want to run it for more than 15 mins..what should I DO?

Comment: Make your app into a legitimate VOIP app, location logging app, or background audio app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading Apple's guide:
[Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: I read this but I am confused about background task expiration handler.How to use it  and where to use.